# C# Delegados, ¿podrías explicarme para que se usan?

Tags: c#, class

Hace poco vi la existencia de los delegados, y quería implementarla, hasta dónde he entendido es la idea de poder pasar funciones como parametros de otra función...

Tengo lo siguiente, una clase instanciada en el objeto Sql, que tiene un método conectar, éste devuelve un enum según lo ocurrido.

Por otra parte, tengo una función que acepta como parámetro un enum, y es void. Dejo la función a continuación.

### Función

---

```
   private void TryToConnect (GeorgiaSQL.Conexion Status){

        switch (Status)
        {
            case GeorgiaSQL.Conexion.ConexionCorrecta:
                Form2 Form = new Form2();
                Form.Show();
                break;

            case GeorgiaSQL.Conexion.ConexionIncorrecta:
               // Usuario incorrecto.
                break;

            case GeorgiaSQL.Conexion.CuentaBaneada:
                // Usuario baneado.
                break;

            case GeorgiaSQL.Conexion.DatosIncompletos:
                // Datos incompletos.
                break;

            case GeorgiaSQL.Conexion.IntentoDeHack:
                // Intento de hack
                break;

            case GeorgiaSQL.Conexion.NoHayInternet:
                // No hay Internet
                break;

            default:
                // ¿CÓMO COJONES HAS LLEGADO AQUÍ?
                break;
        }
    }
```

### Intento fallido de usar un delegado...

---

Vale, entonces, si queremos obtener el enum, debemos llamar al método `Conectar` del `objeto SQL` de la clase `GeorgiaSQL`, pasarle los parametros usuario y contraseña, y el método nos devuelve el enum. En definitiva, llamo a la función `TryToConnect` a la que le paso el método Conectar, para obtener el enum y pasarselo a la primera función...

Lo he hecho con delegados y sin ellos, de la siguiente forma.

```
Action<GeorgiaSQL.Conexion> Delegate = TryToConnect;
Delegate(Sql.Conectar(User.Text, Password.Text));


TryToConnect(Sql.Conectar(User.Text, Password.Text));
```

### En definitiva; ¿para qué sirve un delegado?

---

Sin embargo, aunque ambas funcionan, no le veo sentido a usar el delegado. ¿Podríais explicarme el uso de los delegados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los delegados son tipos de datos, que en este caso especifican el "tipo" de una función/método. Ya que son tipos, puedes usarlos para declarar variables, igual que si pusieras:

```
string a = "hola";
```

Al ser tipos, puedes también definirlos para los parámetros de funciones/métodos. Ejemplo:

```
// declaración del tipo delegate
public delegate bool FiltrarDelegate(string cadena);
```

O hacer un método que regrese una variable tipo delegado:

```
public FiltrarDelegate CrearDelegado()
{
    // ...
    return new FiltrarDelegado....
}
```

Un ejemplo de un método que recibe un parámetro tipo delegado:

```
// un método que recibe un parámetro de ese tipo delegado
void Guardar(FiltrarDelegate filtroFunc, params string[] lista)
{
    foreach (var str in lista)
    {
        if (filtroFunc(str))
        {
            // hacer algo con str
        }
}
```

Y se podría usar:

```
void GuardarLista()
{
    Guardar(new FiltrarDelegate(delegate(str) str.Length < 4)), "uno", "dos", "tres");
}
```

Si tienes un método que coincida con los parametros y tipo de retorno del delegado, lo puedes pasar en la función, ejemplo:

```
bool MetodoNormal(string str)
{
    return str.Length < 4;
}
```

Y lo pasas asi:

```
Guardar(MetodoNormal, "uno", "dos", "tres");
```

Desde las versiones más recientes de c# existen los delegados anónimos y las expresiones lambda, el ejemplo anterior podría escribirse asi:

```
void Guardar(Func<string, bool> filtroFunc, params string[] lista)...
```

y la usarías así:

```
Guardar(str => str.Length < 4,  "uno", "dos", "tres");
```

Todo Linq está basado en delegados y funciones lambda.

Otro uso es en eventos, los eventos en si son delegados, si has manjeado eventos seguro has visto o usado algo así:

```
public event EventHandler Evento;

...

if (Evento != null)
{
    Evento(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Basicamente Evento es un variable de campo de tipo delegado.

Comment: esta pregunta ya tiene respuesta y ha sido marcada como duplicada